# Nodejs to Couchbase Server timed out

Tags: node.js, couchbase, connection-timeout

My app is actually running fine when I started it and keep an eye on it for few hours.

BUT later time(I'm not sure what exact time of inactivity), It does show "Server timed out"  (I crop some logs below)

```
[ERROR] (server - L:463) <node.mycouchbase.server:11210> (SRV=0x2111c60,IX=4) Server timed out. Some commands have failed
[INFO] (confmon - L:166) Not applying configuration received via CCCP. No changes detected. A.rev=152466, B.rev=152466
[INFO] (cccp - L:110) Re-Issuing CCCP Command on server struct 0x2116980
[ERROR] (cccp - L:133) <NOHOST:NOPORT> Got I/O Error=0x17
[INFO] (cccp - L:110) Re-Issuing CCCP Command on server struct 0x2185e30
```

All just working fine again when I restart my Node.js app (Expressjs app).
This problem seem regularly happening

Please give me some suggestion what could be actually problems behind.

Thanks

Comment: What version of the node.js client SDK are you using?

Comment: I'm on Node.js 5.5.0 and Couchbase Node SDK 2.1.3.

Comment: Can you share your connection code?  And are you creating a singleton or are you trying to open a connection per every request?